# C regexec does not find the longest match with a simple greedy regex

Tags: c, regex, posix, glibc, regex-greedy

I am trying to match `m*` to the two "m"s in `immunity`. I read the POSIX `regex.h` manpage and wrote the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

#define DIE(condition, msg) do { \
  if (condition) { \
    puts(msg); \
    return 1; \
  } \
} while (0)

int main(void) {
  regex_t preg;
  regmatch_t match;
  DIE (regcomp(&preg, "m*", REG_EXTENDED), "Failed to compile regex.");
  DIE (regexec(&preg, "immunity", 1, &match, 0), "No regex match found");
  printf("Match starts at %d and ends at %d.", match.rm_so, match.rm_eo);
  return 0;
}
```

`regexec` reports a match (returns 0), but `rm_so` and `rm_eo` are both equal to 0. While this *is* a match (an empty string right at the beginning), the manpage implied that the longest match would always be returned first, in which case 1 and 3 should be returned. When I change the regex to `m+` it works as expected (1, 3, not 1, 2, which means that it is greedy). What is going on here?

Comment: You asked to return the first match and you got it. There is nothing about greediness here, both `*`  and `+`  are greedy.

Comment: A key detail that doesn't seem to be covered by the duplicate is that a POSIX RE engine always takes the _earliest_ match in the string, even if it could make a longer match by starting later in the string.  Length of the match only comes into play if there are two or more possible matches starting from the same point.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html .